# En-Decrypt NSData with RNCryptManager over CoreData

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, encryption, nsdata

I have never anything to do with data encryption, So i started to [work with this code](http://robnapier.net/blog/aes-commoncrypto-564)

I had done anything, and it works all right if I encrypt some `NSData` and directly Decrypt the `NSData`. But it is very hard to understand how this code work. It would be nice anyone can help me.

I would store some Encrypted `NSData` in the `CoreData` and load it from the `CoreData` to DeCrypt it, but if I do this I got this output:

> 2013-03-19 15:31:07.197 En-Decrypt+CoreData[2603:c07]  Assertion failure in +[RNCryptManager AESKeyForPassword:salt:], /Users/main/Desktop/En-Decrypt+CoreData/En-Decrypt+CoreData/RNCryptManager.m:110
>   2013-03-19 15:31:07.198 En-Decrypt+CoreData[2603:c07] Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Unable to create AES key for password: -1'

I have uploaded the [sample xcode project here](http://www.sendspace.com/file/z5u8gy)

Thanks for your help

Comment: The error message indicates that you're feeding garbage for at least one of the arguments of the method you're calling. You need to figure out why. You have not provided enough information for anyone else to figure out why. Maybe you didn't store the value? Maybe you didn't read it back correctly? Maybe you read it but somehow corrupted it before trying to call this method? It could be any number of things.

Comment: Note that RNCryptManager has been superseded by RNCryptor, which provides additional security protections. It will automatically manage the IV and Salt for you. https://github.com/rnapier/RNCryptor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Among with data you need to save `salt` and `iv` values. This is required for decryption.
So modify your data model:
[image]

And save `salt` and `iv` with encrypted data.